# Cheerio: How to select element by text content?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I have some HTML like this:

```
<span id="cod">Code:</span> <span>12345</span>
<span>Category:</span> <span>faucets</span>
```

I want to fetch the category name ("faucets").
This is my trial:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html.contents);
var category = $('span[innerHTML="Category:"]').next().text();
```

But this doesn't work (the `innerHTML` modifier does not select anything).

Any clue?

Comment: You can't give your items a class?

Comment: Item is not 'mine' :-) I'm parsing an external page I do not control...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because `[innerHTML]` is an attribute selector, and `innerHTML` isn't an attribute on the element (which means that nothing is selected).

You could filter the `span` elements based on their text. In the example below, `.trim()` is used to trim off any whitespace. If the text equals 'Category:', then the element is included in the filtered set of returned elements.

```
var category = $('span').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === 'Category:';
}).next().text();
```

---

The above snippet will filter elements if their text is exactly 'Category:'. If you want to select elements if their text *contains* that string, you could use the `:contains` selector (as pointed out in the comments):

```
var category = $('span:contains("Category:")').next().text();
```

Alternatively, using the `.indexOf()` method would work as well:

```
var category = $('span').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf('Category:') > -1;
}).next().text();
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Didn't know about `filter()`, I'm feeling quite dumb... :-(

Comment: If he wants to check if it contains the string he can also just use `$('span:contains("Category:")')`

Comment: @Paulpro Does Cheerio have a `:contains` selector? I checked [the documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), and I didn't see it in there, so I didn't use it.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I don't know Cheerio, but the tag wiki says it's an implementation of jQuery core, so I would assume so.

Comment: @JoshCrozier It appears that it uses this library for selectors, which supports contains: https://www.npmjs.com/package/CSSselect

Answer (score 12):

A simpler solution is:

```
var category = $('span:contains("Category:") + span').text()
```

This is css plus the `:contains` pseudo that is part of jQuery and supported by cheerio.