# How do I get a specific elements value that has no unique identifiers with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm trying to get a specific elements value with Cheerio however I'm unsure how. I've looked over the documentation and so far, no dice.

Website [example](https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/dayz/16108490) of the value I'm trying to get, specifically the `<dd>` that holds the number value of player count.

```
const URL = 'https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/dayz/16108490';
axios(URL)
.then(response => {
    const html = response.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const players = []
    $('.server-info', html).each(function() {
        const scrape_test = $(this).text()
        const pNum = $(this).find('dd').val()
        players.push({
            scrape_test,
            pNum
        })
    })
    console.log(players)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

scrape_test is just ensuring that I'm actually receiving data and it does indeed grab the data including the value I need however I don't know how to refine it to grab specifically what I need.

The response from pNum is undefined, I've tried removing .val() in which I then receive 6 array elements however when I try to iterate over them  to push them out, I then get another undefined. If I pick a specific position I equally get an undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the player count value, you can filter `<dt>` elements by their text contents, then pull the next element to find the corresponding `<dd>`:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const dt = [...$("dt")]
  .find(e => $(e).text().trim().toLowerCase() === "player count");
console.log($(dt).next().text()); // => 7/65
```

Another option is the `:contains()` pseudoselector and the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```js
const text = $('dt:contains("Player count") + dd').text();
```

See also [Cheerio: How to select element by text content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709765/cheerio-how-to-select-element-by-text-content)

<sub>cheerio 1.0.0-rc.12</sub>